# Data exract from MSSQL database with DISTINCT and Max

Tags: sql, sql-server, max, distinct

I have a simple problem to solve. I need to get data from MS SQL and I cannot figure out what I have done wrong and missing.

I have 1 table called "Deliveries" with columns: dID, sNumber and Team. dID is unique number.

I should get following list:
 sNumber , max(dID), Team.

There are several sNumber values and I need distinct list of those - and that is ok with query:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT SerialNumber 
    FROM ProtoDelivery 
    WHERE (Team = 18)
```

Result being:
   Lx1300021,
   Lx1300025,
   Lx1300027,
 ...

How could I get for those MAX(dID) and Team for that dID?

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
 SELECT DISTINCT SerialNumber 
    FROM ProtoDelivery 
    WHERE (Team = 18)  and Id = (select Max(dID) from ProtoDelivery  where Team = 18)
```

Answer (score 0):

Now I found it. It was too easy:
SELECT        MAX(dID) AS Expr1, Team, SerialNumber
FROM            ProtoDelivery
GROUP BY SerialNumber, Team
HAVING        (Team = 18)